# Oracle Sql: add column which counts the rows, starting at 1 each time anothers column value changes

Tags: sql, oracle

I guess this one is discussed already, but I didn`t find it. I am new to sql using the oracle sql developer.

Here is an example of my problem:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egile.png)

At the moment the Depot_ID is the unique primary key which is generated by a sequence and trigger before inserting the data. Instead of this approach I want to create the table to have a new column which counts ascending starting from 1 each time the second column in the example has a new value. How do I create the third column in the example? (Then I want to drop the first column and use the second and third column as composite primary key, but I fail at creating column 3)

Thank you for any tips, Alex

Answer (score 0):

You use the `row_number()` function:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by foreign_key_1 order by depot_id) as new_column
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! The query works perfectly. In my code it is: select DEPOTS.*,
       row_number() over (partition by FK_CLIENT_ID order by FK_CLIENT_ID) as POSITION_NR
     from DEPOTS